# Uninstall Ubuntu 14.04 x64 that runs with Win8 and Ubuntux86

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uninstall

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit on my system that already have Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit installed.

I want to uninstall the 64 bit version now. How can I do that?

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? Ubuntu 32bit can only be BIOS, but 64 bit Ubuntu can be either BIOS or UEFI and Windows can be BIOS or UEFI. If drive is gpt partitioned and you have Windows then you have UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

First create a ubuntu x86 live usb
You can use OS-uninstaller to uninstall Ubuntu x64 (or boot from usb and simply delete the ubuntu x64 partition) and repir grub with boot-repair using ubuntu x86 live usb.

Use the graphical method in this link to repair grub.
http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

@Jye Ramirez: Boot partition is a separate partition ( small size like 300MB like that) to install boot loader. Eg: SYSTEM partition is created if windows is installed. windows stores its boot loader in system partition. If that system partition is deleted windows cant boot. Generally no need to create a separate boot partition you can install boot-loader to OS partition

Comment: Hi @Sudheer. Thanks. Can you tell me what this means:
Important: If you have a separate boot partition, skip the above command and mount the boot partition at /mnt/boot. If you don’t know whether you have a separate boot partition, you probably don’t.